# How do I replace a path and filename string with unknown characters?

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove the version string from `.css` and `.js` files and update the path, so that this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/file.js?version=c0af26a3543415d554bae1b8de55874b7736071d"></script>
```

Becomes this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/new/path/file.js"></script>
```

I used `DomDocument` and it worked great, unfortunately it broke other scripts inside the body of the document, so I need to find an alternative method. I tried strpos, which kind of worked, but only returned the string and not all of the HTML.

I'm scraping a site and saving the files locally, so I need to remove the versioning and update the paths. The version string is generated with git hash, so while they hash string may change, it'll always be 40 characters. That's what I'm trying to remove....

Edit
I was playing around with something like this, but it wasn't outputting what I wanted, so I opened this question; I just don't have enough experience with regex...

```php
if (strpos($html, $str) !== false) {
    $html = substr_replace($str,'',45,49);
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: Converting matches of the following pattern to empty strings works for the example, but only you can say if it works in your general case: `/(?<=\.js)[^>"\r\n]*/`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/kfnEHR/1/) That's the problem of stating a question in terms of a single example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The problem is that I'm scraping a site and saving it locally, so the paths and versioning need to be updated. The versioning is using git hash, so even though the version string may change, it'll always be 40 characters. I'm just trying to figure out how to remove them throughout the document.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/5) help? Or more specifically [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/6)?

Comment: @Mandy8055 REALLY close! Unfortunately it also changes `<script src="//foobar.domain.com/?v2020.1.LTS">` to `<script src="//foobar.domain.com/">`

Comment: Please check the second link which I attached @timgavin. [**This**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/6) one.

Comment: @Mandy8055 That's the one to which I was referring. :)

Comment: Please check [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/10). It is working fine

Comment: @Mandy8055 I fixed the issue and it's working great now. Could you post this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
(<script type="text\/javascript".*)\?(.*?)(".*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(<script type="text\/javascript".*)`** - Represents first capturing group matching `<script type=text/javascript` **literally** along with everything that appears before a `?`.
>
> **`\?(.*?)`** - Represents second capturing group **lazily** matching `?` and everything before the first `"`.
>
> **`(".*)`** - Represents third matching group **greedily** matching everything after.
>
> **`$1$3`** - For the replacement part since you've to get rid of the second capturing group; just append first and third together.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/10)

---

**Sample Implementation in php:**

```
<?php
$re = '/(<script type="text\/javascript".*)\?(.*?)(".*)/m';
$str = '<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/file.js?version=c0af26a3543415d554bae1b8de55874b7736071d"></script>

<script src="//foobar.domain.com/?v2020.1.LTS">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/path2/file.css?version=sfsjfsbfsj00320vfvfv9494914411"></script>
';
$subst = '$1$3';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/ByImcyDTU)

Answer (score 0):

See [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$HTML='<script src="/path/file.js?version=c0af26a3543415d554bae1b8de55874b7736071d"></script>';

$Result=preg_replace('/".*\/([\w\d]+)\.(css|js).*"/','/new/path/${1}.${2}',$HTML);

echo"$Result";
```

Comment: Really close! But returns this `<script type=/new/path/file.js></script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript" src="/new/path/file.js"></script>`

Comment: It actually returns as you requested (`<script src=...`) and is shorter than the other answer. I removed the `type` attribute in the sample as it is not needed. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-script-element.html

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$oldString = htmlspecialchars('<script type="text/javascript" src="/many/parents/path/file.js?version=c0af26a3543415d554bae1b8de55874b7736071d"></script>');

$newString = preg_replace_callback('#(src=&quot;)(/?)(\w*/)+([\w\d]*)(.js|.css)(\?version=)([\w\d]*)#', function($matches){return $matches[1].'/new/dir/'.$matches[4].$matches[5];}, $oldString);

echo $newString;
```